# read multiline strings with ruby, broken by "\"

Tags: ruby, file, parsing

in some RPM spec files (for instance), there are multiline strings which look like:

```
%build
export CFLAGS="%{optflags} -fomit-frame-pointer \
-W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -fPIE"
export LDFLAGS="-pie"
%configure --disable-silent-rules \
  gl_cv_func_printf_directive_n=yes \
  gl_cv_func_printf_infinite_long_double=yes
```

if i for instance try to parse this file with the following snippet:

```
if = File.open("foo.spec")

f.each do |line|
  puts line if line =~ /CFLAGS/m
end
```

the line will be printed incomplete. The "-W -Wall ... -fPIE" won't be printed.

There is any way to catch it?

Answer (score 2):

You're reading your ruby file line by line. Since it's plain text, the result is **correct**. However, if you want to keep *command* lines together, you need to concatenate them. Instead of iterating on each line, you can parse the whole text with regular expressions:

```
file = File.open("foo.spec")
# Read the file's content as a string.
content = file.read

# Split the content by lines
raw_lines = content.split /\r?\n/

# Iterate each line
lines = raw_lines.inject([]) do |acc, line|
  # Add to the last if the previous lines ends with a \ character
  if acc[-1].to_s =~ /\\\s*$/
    acc[-1] += line
    acc
  # Otherwise, register it as a new line
  else
    acc << line
  end
end

# The result will be an array with all your lines.
lines.each do |line|
  puts line if line =~ /CFLAGS/m
end

# Don't forget to close the file stream!
file.close
```

If you want to remove the `/` characters between your *multi-line* lines to transform them into one line, you need to replace them:

```
line.gsub! "\\", ' '    # Replace multi-lines characters
```

Comment: looks like your solution chops off some characters in the end of line

Comment: @VP Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: with the input that I provided, your code work almost as expected. However its missing the last double quote. In the real rpm spec, some text is missing

Comment: I'm thinking, you are in the right track.. Maybe I won't split the string, but maybe join lines which end in "\"

Comment: You're right. The previous solution trimmed the last character of each line. I've updated the answer to use the solution you'd explained in your last comment. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I found the example above seemed to chop off the last character on each line, so here is another alternative:

```
IO.read("foo.spec").split(/(?<!\\)\n/).select{|x| x =~ /CFLAGS/ }
```